# There are 40% more girls than boys.

Tags: probability

The question here is how to express that mathemathically. I think it would be: let´s say #**boys**= b and #**girls** = g, then $b +\frac {4b}{10} = g$. Tell me if I am correct and I´d like you to give me more examples please. That was part of a question a saw so if I can´t solve it or something I´ll probably post it here. What if if were the opposite, I mean that the $g$ would be $40$% less than $b$.($b-\frac {4}{10}b =g$ ?)

Comment: Yes, you are corect.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $40\%$ more girls than boys would mean $~g= \frac{140~b}{100}~$ (or simply $g=1.4\,b$ ) if $g$ is the count for girls and $b$ the count for boys.